# How do I profile an Azure app running in the Compute Emulator?

Tags: azure, profile

I think profiling an application deployed to Azure is not a big deal http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh369930.aspx

I'd like to do the same locally, in the Compute Emulator. It looks like this is currently difficult http://www.pettijohn.com/2011/05/performance-testing-azure-dev-fabric.html at best, at least with the native VisualStudio 2010 profiler.

Am I missing a simple way to do this? Are there any third-party tools that make this fairly easy to do?

I'm using the Azure SDK 1.4 and Azure Tools for Visual Studio 2010 1.3

Answer (score 6):

For later versions of the SDK you can refer to this [article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/profiling-in-visual-studio/) in the Windows Azure documentation, where it is explained how to do CPU sampling for both worker roles and web roles: for the latter case, you should attach to the `WaIISHost.exe` process.

As also indicated in the answer from Marcus Jansson, you may need to attach to the `w3wp.exe` process. For example, when I'm debugging one of the web sites contained in a web role I need to explicitly attach to the `w3wp.exe` process that is hosting that site, since Visual Studio does not attach automatically to all relevant IIS instances.

**UPDATE 2013-01-10 19:03 UTC** I was unable to profile web roles using the linked instructions. I discovered that:

- it is useless to attach to `WaIISHost.exe`, since it seems that it doesn't contain the role code;
- I cannot attach to `w3wp.exe` instances from Visual Studio 2010 (I receive an error message with code VSP1449).

Since I'm using Windows Azure SDK 1.8, I then tried to run my web role under IIS Express (see [this post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/nunogodinho/archive/2012/06/07/iis-express-support-for-local-development-in-windows-azure-sdk-1-7.aspx) for further details) and then I attached to the `iisexpress.exe` process. This way I was able to profile my web site.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this!

Answer (score 1):

If you run the web role in IIS, you can just attach to the process `w3wp.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you're trying to profile.

The link you included in your question is for profiling memory for a web role, and yes it looks a little involved.

If you're looking to profile a worker role, it's much easier.  You can simply start the worker role through Visual Studio (or using the method mentioned in the post you linked to if you're worried about the effect of the debugger on the profiling) and select Analyze -> Profiler Attach/Detach -> WaWorkerHost.  From there it should look just like profiling any other application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have mentioned that I'm working with web roles (alas).